# Why is there a short tone in the ATC recording that cuts the pilot transmission using VOX?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, radio

I had an experience of listening to tower-to-pilot conversation and noticed that there was a short tone in the audio stream that suppresses the voice/audio signal and causes muting on the recording. I have a copy of the recording and the tone is around 100 Hz sawtooth wave. In the recording from the radio, it cuts the voice of the pilot while in the recording extracted from the module, there is this 100Hz sawtooth wave tone with around 0.5sec duration. Anyone has idea what might be causing this?

Comment: How were you "listening to tower-to-pilot conversation?" Where did the "recording" come from? Can _we_ also have a copy? What is the "module" from which you say it was extracted? The more detail you can provide, the more likely you'll get a good answer.

Comment: There were two recordings, one from the operator module in the tower, and the other is from the radio interface board. The recording from the radio interface board has short muting on the pilot transmission, while the recording from the operator module in the tower includes the tone which causes the muting from the radio interface board recording.

Comment: Attached is a cut version of the transmission
during the tones in this recording, it signifies the muting on the other recording, just the same duration of the beep.
https://voca.ro/16rplfD4x9fc

Comment: @TypeIA , maybe you know something on this? I can't seem to find out where the tone comes from. One assumption is that it is from a coupled frequency, however, the reason for this tone is still unknown even if the tone is indeed coming from the coupled frequency.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I can only say it doesn't sound like the normal heterodyne squeal that happens when two stations transmit simultaneously. I would follow up with the source of the data (facility or equipment manufacturer).

Comment: I see. Thanks for taking the time...unfortunately, i won't be able to provide with such details on the manufacturer and other details. Just that this uses frequency coupling, and the audio is improved if we de-couple it.

Comment: This one is also using analog radio... Could it be coming from the signaling? (i.e. squelch) -this is affecting various frequencies-

Comment: perhaps a notch filter might help ...but... :(